# HQL: how can I maintain sort order when fetching complete rows using a where-in-subselect construct?

Tags: database, hibernate, hql, subquery

I am currently creating a feature like 'other people who liked this also like'.

The HQL statement in question returns a list of product ids (ordered by count of shared 'likes' between two products). But the result is not distinct - stripped down to the very basics, the query looks something like this. (Please note: it's not the original query, rather a simplified example to give you an idea of what I am doing)

```
select prd2.id from UserLike ul2
join ul2.product prd2
where ul.userId in (
    select ul.userId from UserLike ul
    join ul.product prd
    where prd.id=:productId
)
group by prd2.id
order by count(prd2.id) desc
```

Starting from there, is there a common pattern to retrieve the complete row/entity for each product?

In SQL I'd use the query above as a subselect within FROM and join back to the product table.

As HQL does not support subselects within FROM, I do not think there is another way than to wrap

```
from product p where p.id in (SUBSELECT_AS_ABOVE)
```

but there goes the sorting. :(

Maybe this sounds a bit weird, but I think this is a common use case - so are there any common workarounds for this?

Thanks a lot in advance and best regards,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two steps:
1. Get list if IDs (which you have already done);
2. Get all products by IDs list.
You can do that with Expression.In("Id", idList) where idList is IList result from first query.

Also, if only possible, try to do everything w/o HQL but with criteria and restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't Expression.in the very same as where p.id in (...) in my statement above, i.e. discarding the order of the ids?

Comment: btw: Personally I like HQL a lot more than Criteria, easier to write, easier to read. In my book, Criteria are only better if when there is need to build very complex and flexible queries.

Comment: ... but if there is any way to achieve this using Criteria, I'd have to reconsider my opinion about HQL vs. Criteria. So if it is possible, please let me know :) I still could not find out how this can be done.